# Is there any Ruby CouchDB wrapper which behaves like ActiveRecord adapter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, couchdb

There are several good CouchDB wrappers available, like SimplyStored, CouchFoo, CouchRest and others, but none of them seems to mimic ActiveRecord adapter. To be precise, what I need is:

1. Setting database access parameters in `config/database.yml` in a common way instead of adding some magical commands to `config/environments.rb`.
2. Support for code-generating commands like `rails generate scaffold` or `rails generate model`.
3. Support for the features that RDBs and DDBs have in common (transactions and so on).

What I do not expect them to do:

1. Be fully compatible with relational database adapters (in other words, I do not expect everything to work after just changing `adapter: couchdb` to `adapter: sqlite3`).
2. Mimic any particular ORM feature.

So, the question is, does such adapter already exist? And if not, is there some reason people do not implement this? I am thinking about writing such adapter myself or maybe adding this functionality to some existing wrapper, but I'd like to make sure I don't miss something.

Answer (score 0):

> So, the question is, does such adapter
>   already exist?

No, it doesn't.

> And if not, is there some reason
>   people do not implement this?

Because CouchDB is not a relational database. If you need a RDB, then you probably want to use ActiveRecord, not forcing a Document Database to behave like a Relational Database.

[CouchRest CouchModel](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model/issues) is a project which uses an API very similar to ActiveRecord. In facts, it implements `ActionModel` without loosing the focus that CouchDB is not a Relational Database.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I do not need CouchDB to be relational. I just need an adapter to store credentials and generate code in a uniform way.

Comment: ActiveRecord defines an API for Relational Databases. CouchDB is not a relational database, thus the same API won't fit.

Comment: ActiveRecord adapters also manage code generation and global operations like connection/disconnection and transactions, which can be applied to CouchDB too. I do not need any relational part of its functionality, just the subset of operations which are the same for RDBs and DDBs.

Comment: And again, I am happy with existing CouchDB models, I need Rails management tools to work with CouchDB. But thank you for mentioning CouchREST, because after reading its docs once again I found reference to https://github.com/hpoydar/couchrest-rails which seems to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you are looking for, @langalex' CouchPotato, which builds on CouchRest is an approximation: https://github.com/langalex/couch_potato